# Pulling through additional data from logged in user with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to modify the script below to pull additional information from the database when the user is redirected.

The extra information I want to pull through is in the same table as *username* and *password* and is labeled *fname*. I am very new to php so any help to point me in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

I know I could use the *username* (and that does work if I replace *fname* with *username* in the script on the redirected page) but that is an email so does not look good as a greeting to a *logged on* user

**Here is the script to log in the user and redirect that is working fine:**

```
<?php

session_start();
$host="localhost";  // Host name 
$username="";       // Mysql username 
$password="";       // Mysql password 
$db_name="trydata"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users";  // Table name

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); 

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection) 
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername); 
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword); 
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername); 
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword); 

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM $tbl_name 
        WHERE username='$myusername' 
        AND password='$mypassword'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row 
$count = mysql_num_rows($result); 

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword,
// table row must be 1 row 
if($count == 1){ 
  // Register $myusername, $mypassword
  // and redirect to file"login_success.php" 
  $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername; 
  $_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword; 

  // get the result set from the query
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

  // get the redirect column's value
  $redirect = trim($result['redirect']);

  if ($redirect == '') {
    echo "No redirect value was set!";
  } else {
    header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    exit;
  }
} else { 
  echo "Wrong Username or Password"; 
} 

?>
```

**Here is the script in the redirected page that is not pulling through the fname from the database:**

```
<?php 

// start up your PHP session! 
session_start();

if ($_SESSION["username"]) {
  echo "You are logged in as ".$_SESSION['fname'];
  echo "<p>";
  echo "<a href='aapage.php'>here is the aapage</a>";
  echo "<a href='logout.php'> Click here to logout<a/>";
} else {
  header ("Location: form.php");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to assign fname to a variable. For example, after the line:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

You can add something like:

```
$_SESSION['fname'] = $result['fname'];
```

You can then use this session variable in other pages.

Comment: Now now got it working with your help, thanks very much for taking your time to help me. Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks again, regards Ala.

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting your session variable 'frame'. You need to set it in your log in script.

```
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row 
if($count == 1){ 
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file"login_success.php" 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername; 
    $_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword; 
    $_SESSION['frame'] = mysql_result($result,0,"whateverfnamesrowisinyourdatabase");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, now got it working with your help and help from the person below, thanks again your help is very much appreciated.